# EF 6.1.3 with SQL Server geography column

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

I have in my SQL Server a column that uses geography type, EF5 works like a charm with this, after upgrading to EF 6.1.3 I´m getting the message:

> The property 'GeoLocalition' on the type 'Address' has a property type of 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography' which cannot be mapped to a primitive type.

I already checked all the `System.Data` references and change to `System.Data.Entity.Spatial` but I keep getting the same error.

Anybody had fixed this?

Update:
I was checking the page witch throws the error and I just realize that is the DevExpress Component throwing the error. On my model and class code is everything right, I will open an ticket with them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22598938/496680

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20729185/entity-framework-6-and-spatial-data